# Assign a value based on if condition in Scala

Tags: scala, while-loop, scope

I have a while loop that needs to create an object based on a condition happening inside the loop. The code runs fine but the object is not available once the loop finishes.

I suspect I am missing something about how variable scope works in Scala.

If what I am trying is not possible, I would like to understand why and what the alternatives are.

This is a simple example

```scala
var i = 0

while (i < 5) {
    val magicValue = if (i==2) i
    i += 1
}

println(magicValue) // error: not found: value magicValue
```

This is how I would do it in python

```py
i = 0

while i<5:
    if (i==2):
        magic_value = i
    i += 1

print(magic_value) # prints 2
```

Comment: Please consider using one of the answers of the higher scoring. altough the accepted answer works, it is much more Scala way to use the other approaches.

Comment: @TomerShetah thank you for your detailed answer below, which I would also tick if I could select two answers. My question was "How do I fix my while loop and, if I can't, what would be alternatives". Isarikaya provides a direct answer, while you provide an alternative. Although the monad approach is more legitimate, and certainly something I am learning, using a while loop is not forbidden, forces me to understand mutable variable behaviour, and fits the broader problem on which this simplified question is based.

Comment: As long as you are happy  . I am just saying what I think you should know while choosing one implementation or another.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Please read this article
[read](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/two-types-variables.html)

You should use var instead of val. If you use val, this value cannot be used except in the if scope.

```
var i = 0
var magicValue = 0
while (i < 5){
  if(i==2) magicValue = i
   i += 1
}
println(magicValue)
```

[demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/j9dr5KaKSgu2ktTanq8uUQ)

> Each variable declaration is preceded by its type.
> By contrast, Scala has two types of variables:
> val creates an immutable variable (like final in Java)
> var creates a mutable variable

Comment: `If you use val, this value cannot be used except in the if scope` is what I thought happens but I couldn't find it in the docs, thanks for this. Using a mutable variable makes perfect sense then.

Comment: Actually your code as it stands throws an error: `error: type mismatch; found   : Unit;  required: Int`. I changed the if condition to `magicValue = if (i==2) i else magicValue` and it's ok now. Does the `if` need to return an `Int` in any case, otherwise it's considered a `Unit` type?

Comment: Lol you right I overlooked it. But instead of saying it, you can edit it politely.

Comment: I removed my downvote, because at least the code works now. But I'm not going to upvote it because I think it is not a good practice in Scala to use `var` and `while` as you suggest.

Comment: @TomerShetah I would keep the downvote because the answer promotes bad practice. It is also somewhat misleading: "Each variable declaration is preceded by its type" (the type comes afterward; `val` is not a type) and "If you use val, this value cannot be used except in the if scope" (implies `val` changes the scope when it's really the location where the variable is declared).

Comment: I stated the difference between val and var that the questioner is looking for and in the answer. Why did you get stuck with the code?

Answer (score 3):

In the same way you wouldn't feed bird-seed to a dog, you shouldn't try to write Python code using Scala. Learning a new language is more than new syntax. It's also new idioms and new ways to think about problem solving.

```
val magicValue = (0 to 5).foldLeft(0){
                       case (mv,i) => if (i==2) i else mv}
```

Comment: The range-based example was to simplify the real problem. If instead of a bounded sequence we had to loop through a doubly linked list, would the monad approach help? I would love to give the dog a proper meal if it can digest it.

Comment: @mcgl_k then open a new question describing your real problem and showing your solution using `var` that way we could propose a more functional / idiomatic alternative.

Comment: @mchl_k; _"...would the monad approach help?"_ Almost certainly! Post something closer to _"the real problem"_ to learn how.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
println(0.to(5).find(_ == 2).getOrElse(0))
```

[`find`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/IterableOnce.scala#L618) will return an [`Option`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L144), in case there is an element that satisfies the condition. If there is such, it will be printed. Otherwise, the default `0` will be printed.

For example:

```
println(0.to(5).find(_ == 20).getOrElse(0))
```

will print `0`.

There is also a `findLast` method, in case you want the last that satisfies this condition:

```
println(0.to(5).findLast(_ == 2).getOrElse(0))
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/btj4KoqESl6q5aNoYQjTuw/1).